# Symfony 2 - Differents fields for search form than list

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have three entity for a project : Book, Author and Theme. For information, Author and Theme are linked with Book in Many to One/One to Many. A book has one or more author and one or more themes.
And I have generated crud about theses for basics functions (add, edit and delete) and default views/form.

But I need to do some functions search, three exactly:

- Search Book with part of the Title
- Search Book with one Author
- Search Book with one or more Theme.

I coded the three functions and working good but I have a problem about the fields used in search forms.

The first one is correct, it show a input field where we put the title and the book list as result is correct but the two others …

Because of the relationship the field are drop list where the user choose a item and search it, the result is correct but I wish for the second to have an input field for search the author name and the last to display checkbox so I’ve made research but I can’t understand why in my forms type, I can’t change the kind of field I want.

Here my two Forms Type :

Search with one Author : I just want to display an input field and not a list but get error each time

```
<?php namespace Projet\BibliothequeBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class BookByAuthorType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('authors')
    ;
}

/**
 * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
 */
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Projet\BibliothequeBundle\Entity\Book'
    ));
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getName()
{
    return 'authors';
}

}
```

Search Book with one or more Theme : I tried to display chechbox by link the 'themes' array to result of checkbox but don't work too.

```
<?php namespace Projet\BibliothequeBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class BookByThemeType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    // $themes = array();
    // $themes=$builder->add('themes');
    $builder
        ->add('themes', 'choice', [
            'choices' => 'themes',
            'multiple' => true,
            'expanded' => true
        ])
    ;
}

/**
 * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
 */
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Projet\BibliothequeBundle\Entity\Book'
    ));
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getName()
{
    return 'themes';
}
}
```

UPDATE : My BookController functions maybe it's the origin of my problems.

```
// AUTHOR SEARCH FUNCTIONS
public function SearchByAuthorAction() {
    $entity = new Book();
    $form   = $this->CreateSearchAuthorForm($entity); 
    return $this->render('ProjetBibliothequeBundle:Book:searchbyauthor.html.twig', array( 
        'form'   => $form->createView(), 
    )); 
}

private function CreateSearchAuthorForm(Book $entity) {
    $form = $this->createForm(new BookByAuthorType(), $entity, array(
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('book_submit_search_by_author'),
        'method' => 'POST',
    ));

    $form->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Search'));

    return $form;
}

public function SubmitSearchByAuthorAction(Request $request) {
    $entity = new Book();
    $form   = $this->CreateSearchAuthorForm($entity); 
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    $author = $form->get('authors')->getData();

    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()
                       ->getEntityManager()
                       ->getRepository('ProjetBibliothequeBundle:Book');
    $Booklist = $repository->findByAuthor($author);

    return $this->render('ProjetBibliothequeBundle:Book:resultbyauthor.html.twig',  
                      array('Booklist' => $Booklist));
}

//THEME SEARCH FUNCTIONS
public function SearchByThemeAction() {
    $entity = new Book();
    $form   = $this->CreateSearchThemeForm($entity); 
    return   $this->render('ProjetBibliothequeBundle:Book:searchbytheme.html.twig', array( 
        'form'   => $form->createView(), 
    )); 
}

private function CreateSearchThemeForm(Livre $entity) {
    $entities = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('ProjetBibliothequeBundle:Book')->findAll();
    $form = $this->createForm(new BookByThemeType(), $entity, array(
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('book_submit_search_by_theme'),
        'method' => 'POST',
    ));

    $form->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Search'));

    return $form;
}   

public function SubmitSearchByThemeAction(Request $request) {
    $entity = new Book();
    $form   = $this->CreateSearchThemeForm($entity); 
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    $theme = $form->get('themes')->getData();

    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()
                       ->getEntityManager()
                       ->getRepository('ProjetBibliothequeBundle:Book');
    $Booklist = $repository->findByTheme($theme);

    return $this->render('ProjetBibliothequeBundle:Book:resultbytheme.html.twig',  
                      array('Booklist' => $Booklist));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to set `data_class` for `GET` operations. Just create a basic form, may be like this:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('themes', 'choice', [
            'choices' => 'themes',
            'multiple' => true,
            'expanded' => true
        ])
    ;
}

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(['method' => 'GET', 'csrf_protection' => false]);
}
```

in your action catch values from URL, pass them to `findBy` method or manually build you query:

```
public function someAction(Request $request)
{
    ...

    $form->createForm(new FORM_TYPE, null);

    ....

    $filters = $request->query->get($form->getName());

    $result = $entityManager->getRepository(REPOSITORY)->findBy($filters, $orderBy, $limit, $offset);

    ...
}
```

Comment: I have an error : " Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\ChoiceList\SimpleChoiceList::__construct() must be of the type array, string given, called in /.../symfony/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/Type/ChoiceType.php on line 172 and defined in /.../symfony/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/ChoiceList/SimpleChoiceList.php line 45"

Comment: Yes I use three methods in BookRepository which are FindByTitle, FindByThemes and FindByAuthors.

Comment: @Tenebros You should send GET request (no need to set `data_class`), instead of POST, if you only get/fetch data from DB. You're not creating new records, you're just fetching them.

Comment: @Tenebros Where do you get `themes` method in choice list? Is it returning an array? Choice list requires you to provide an array.

Comment: The forms types created by crud for add/edit entity. In the BookType I've see the $builder to add 'titre' , 'authors' and 'themes' and I copy that for my own search themes but that the same as the add/edit form it display a list of themes where you can choose one and search which work but not what I want. I don't understand why 'themes' is not an array but a string because for display a list in my first version I suppose it need to be an array. Maybe get all my themes entity in my controller and pass trought the form but I don't know how to do that.